# Implementing Java Bean Validation with annotations in Spring Batch app

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-batch

I'm attempting to implement JSR 308 validation annotations on my Java Bean being used in a Spring Batch app. Spring Batch provides a `ValidatingItemProcessor`, but I want to validate before I get to the processor step, so I decided to go with the Java annotations.

What I thought I could was add the annotation to a method parameter, and if that parameter didn't validate, the method would never be called. But it's not working that way. Apparently I still have to call `Validator.validate()` first. Am I correct?

This is an example of my bean, with a custom annotation:

```
public void setValue(@NullOrDecimal String value) {
    // I don't want to come into this method if "value" isn't a null or a decimal
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
        this.value = new BigDecimal(value);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints) that described exactly how to achieve my solution. Once I made my POJO a component (which may not have been necessary), Spring began to intercept my methods before the parameters were set. That's what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Your POJO does not have to be a component for that to work, here is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/validator/BeanValidatingItemProcessorTest.java#L27. If you want to apply Bean Validation constraints on your item, you can use  the `BeanValidatingItemProcessor`, the `ValidatingItemProcessor` is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. An annotation on its own does nothing. You should call some code that will introspect this annotations and do something (validation in your case).

Data validation is a typical use case for an item processor, that's why Spring Batch provides the `ValidatingItemProcessor`. You can always chain another processor in a `CompositeItemProcessor` if you want to do some processing on valid items (invalid items will be rejected or filtered and will not continue in the chain).

Comment: Actually Mahmoud, this is one time that you're actually wrong. :-) I found an article that laid out exactly what my beans need to look like to accomplish what I wanted!

Comment: I might be wrong, I have no problem with that. However, I don't think so. If you share your complete code, I can show you where the validation is taking place.

Comment: Thanks for the example! The only problem I have with the `BeanValidatingItemProcessor` is that the fields have to be set in the bean, and then validated. What I wanted was to intercept the values before they make it into the bean.

Comment: That's not how the bean validation API works. The idea of that API is to annotate classes with validation constraints, and call the validation process on populated beans (with valid or invalid data). I don't see how it could validate values before setting them on fields. Who will be calling the validation code in this case?

Comment: With a parameter-level validation annotation and a `MethodValidationPostProcessor`. I also had to annotate my bean at the class-level with `@Validated`. According to the article, `@Validated` drives the validation process automatically, versus a programmatic invocation of the `validate()` method. I hope that makes sense? If not, I'll create a Gist of my code.

Comment: `With a parameter-level validation annotation and a MethodValidationPostProcessor`: You don't need all that, unless you want to. You don't have to call `validate`, Spring Batch will call it for you: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/a7092a21e428cf904f210aff2682b518dc3649c5/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/validator/ValidatingItemProcessor.java#L84 if you declare a `ValidatingItemProcessor ` in your step as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225490/discussion-between-user1660256-and-mahmoud-ben-hassine).