# Spring Batch: Is there a way to keep validating a skipped row?

Tags: validation, spring-batch

My Spring Batch app accepts an Excel file and inputs it into the database. I have javax parameter validation that checks every element before it gets set. Right now, if a cell fails validation, my `SkipPolicy` skips that row and continues onto the next. But I have a new requirement to validate **every cell** in a given row and accumulate all the errors. Right now the only way I could come up to do this is to set individual try-catch blocks around every setter, and then throw an exception at the end. It's messy and cumbersome.

Can I somehow configure my job, say with retry logic or something, to keep **reading** the invalid row, but not pass it to the `Processor`?

Comment: `Is there a way to keep validating a skipped row?`: If it's skipped, why keep validating it? `I have javax parameter validation that checks every element before it gets set`: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115090/implementing-java-bean-validation-with-annotations-in-spring-batch-app#comment115149731_65125989. I don't know why you want to set only valid values on objects. Again, this is not the idea of the bean validation API in the first place.

Comment: If you map each excel row to a POJO where each cell corresponds to a field, then a `BeanValidatingItemProcessor` would throw an exception for invalid items with all validations errors (one for each field or cell) and you could achieve your requirement.